# Add arrows to dropdown menu CF7

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, contact-form-7

I'm using Contact Form 7 on a website of a client, and I styled the dropdown menu to this:

```
.wpcf7-form select {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
color: #72858a;
font-size: 0.7777777778rem;
background-color: #e9edf0;
border-color: #e9edf0;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Unfortunately the arrows are missing now. Is there anyway to add an down arrow at the right side of the dropdown menu in the same color as the text? I tried different css classes found on this website, but nothing seems to work.

Image of how it displays now: [image: Dropdown before]

And how it should be: [image: Dropdown after]

The arrow could also be another arrow.

Any help would be appreciated much!

Regards,
Vasco

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option for you... now... I used the span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap that was specifically around the select I was styling.  You could also (instead) wrap the selects in a custom div.

This produced this result for me

[image: Example]

I also made the triangle using clip-path, so you can change the colors or anything else.

```css
/* Using the menu-813 which for me was the span around the select.*/
span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.menu-813 {
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
    background: #e9edf0;
    display: inline-block;
}
span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.menu-813:after {
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #000;
    right:8px;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 0;
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 50% 100%);
}

.wpcf7-form select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    color: #72858a;
    font-size: 0.7777777778rem;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #e9edf0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 2ch;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but unfortunately it doesn't work at my end. The polygon doesn't show up. Can't figure out why. The rest of the CSS works perfectly fine. Any thoughts maybe?